# Is it possible to set the style of a toolbar at runtime?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-theme

This is a short question:

I know that you can create a toolbar via XML, with specified theme, for example ([**link**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/..."/>
```

In my case, during runtime, the app can have some content to be of either white or dark colors.

Is it possible to set the theme of the Toolbar (of the support library) to have a specific theme, during runtime?

Is it at least possible to set the items inside to have the correct selector and item-tint-color, so that pressing on them will still have a visible effect (changing the color of the background to white, when it was dark, makes the effect invisible)?

Comment: Yes you can change the color of toolbar at run time    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("desired color"));

Comment: @RakshitNawani This I already do, but what about the title, the items, the overflow item, the selectors... All are in a theme. I've changed the background and the title text color, but the items don't look well. I think I should use ViewStub, and decide which toolbar to inflate when needed, but if there is a nicer way to do it, I would like to know about it.

Comment: I will post an answer soon of what I have done to show the toolbar's text color, menu options and buttons in toolbar in different fragments

Answer (score 1):

As I've found, it isn't possible.

However, I can use ViewStub, and when the time comes to put the toolbar with the correct style, I can do it:

**dark_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

**light_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
```

The layout:

```
            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/..."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

The code:

```
    ViewStub viewStub = ...
    viewStub.setLayoutResource(...);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) viewStub.inflate();
```

If I would need to "change the theme" of the toolbar, after it's already shown, I could use a viewSwitcher of 2 toolbars (each of a different theme), and for each function call on one, do it for the other too. And when I need to switch between the themes, I can switch between the views within the viewSwitcher.

Not that same as switching themes, but a nice workaround still.

Comment: But how is this a theme changing? You are switching between toolbar layouts and not the theme attribute.

Comment: I know. As I wrote, this is not possible, so at least I got to have the correct initialized state. Another alternative is to have a viewSwitcher of 2 toolbars (one of each theme), and for each function that you call on one, call it on the other too (adding menu items, for example). When you wish to switch themes, you can switch between the toolbars.

Comment: but yet this isn't a dynamic change in theming, what you doing is a nice workaround that can cause plenty LOC, if your app design has only two themes then that's alright, but how about if you have 10? but yeah as you said, its a workaround that works as intended.

Comment: I know. Dynamic themes aren't quite possible on the same instance of any type of view. As for the example of 10 themes, my solution can extend further. You can have a class that extends ViewAnimator, which holds a toolbar for each theme you wish, and in this class have a function for each Toolbar function, which will call it for each of the toolbars it has. It creates a lot of toolbars (10 in this example), but it will work. Not the perfect solution, but it can work.

Comment: Hmmmm... well this is true, but now that Java 8 is supported, you can use Lambda (though I never did it myself) to go over each toolbar within, and call the function you need on it. So each line of "toolbar.setTitle" (for example) would still be a single line of code, as you call the lambda line to go over each toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method in the `Toolbar` class called
**`setPopupTheme();`**

> Specifies the theme to use when inflating popup menus. By default, uses the same theme as the toolbar itself.

simply to change the toolbar background/popup theme you could create a custom **`class`** that extends **`Toolbar`** and you could post an event to it so it could dynamically change its `background/popup theme` in all the `Activity/Fragments` that the current Stack has.

for example i'm assuming you have an idea in how to use `EventBus` consider the class below:

```
    public class ThemeableToolbar extends Toolbar {


    private boolean isSemiTransparent;

    public ThemeableToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ThemeableToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ThemeableToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        int primary = PrefHelper.getInt(PrefConstant.PRIMARY_COLOR);
        if (primary == 0) {
            primary = ActivityCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.primary);
        }
        if (isSemiTransparent()) {
            AnimUtil.animateColorChange(this, ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(primary, 40), null);
        } else {
            AnimUtil.animateColorChange(this, primary, null);
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    public void onEvent(ThemeModel themeModel) {
        init();
    }

    public boolean isSemiTransparent() {
        return isSemiTransparent;
    }

    public void setIsSemiTransparent(boolean isSemiTransparent) {
        this.isSemiTransparent = isSemiTransparent;
        setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(ViewHelper.getPrimaryColor(getContext()), 40));
    }
}
```

**ThemeModel**  is just a plain java class that being passed to the `EventBus` `onEvent` to notify it.

**Edit**  to be able to change the whole `Activity Theme` i'd suggest you that you have a `BaseActivity` that registers an event to be passed to it and when the event is received you should then recreate your activity by calling `recreate();` which will cause the activities that extends `BaseActivity` to be recreated. before calling `super.onCreate(....)` in your `BaseActivity` make sure you set the desired theme. maybe store a reference in android `Preferences` so you could know which theme to set?

Comment: I don't think this changes how the items are showns and their selectors, so it's not full-theme changing support. I meant something like the theme that I set on XML. Anyway, I think that like on other themes setting, this needs a ViewStub or something.